# Phase diagrams for stainless steels

Tags: materials-engineering, alloys, phase-diagram

A stainless steel is a ferritic alloy, in general, with a low carbon content and a Cr content equal to or greater than 10.5%. To study the phase transformations and heat treatments undergone by these steels, a phase diagram is used, as shown in the following figure:

[image]

In this diagram, there is a sigma phase of tetragonal structure, whose occurrence I have read should be avoided. But, in the notes I am reading, the reason does not appear. Why should the sigma phase be avoided?

Comment: Not an expert in this, but [this site](https://www.industrialheating.com/articles/90371-sigma-phase-embrittlement) suggests that the sigma phase is less corrosion resistant and more brittle than the surrounding phases. I don't know if you are looking for more detail than what's given there.

Comment: Was the comment by Tyberius helpful? Please let us know if you've found an answer or learned anything new about this in the last 5+ months!

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if someone would like to answer or if OP addresses suggestions/questions from the comments.